# SQLite SQL query - 3 level/nesting on same table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need a query that selects rows in a table searching for the maximum value in a given column for each unique pair from two other columns. Consider this very simple example table:

```
a  b  c  d
1  1  0  1
1  1  2  2
1  2  1  1
1  2  3  2
2  1  7  5
2  1  6  4
```

Unique pairs are formed from columns a and b. We look for the maximum in column d. The result returns the corresponding columns a, b and c. So, for the above sample data, the returned results should look like this:

```
a  b  c
1  1  2
1  2  3
2  1  7
```

I have tried nested queries and joins and I haven't reached my goal. I also performed an Google search looking for a discussion and consulted several database books, to no avail. I see plenty of examples of nested queries that involve multiple tables, but none that involve the same table.

It seems the problem requires three passes (nesting):
1) get a set of rows of unique a & b pairs
2) for each row in that set find the maximum value of d: return a set of a, b and d rows
3) for each triplet a, b, and d values, query returning a, b and c columns.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: create table T (a int, b int, c int, d int);
insert into T values (1,1,0,1), (1,1,2,2), (1,2,1,1),
(1,2,3,2),(2,1,7,5),(2,1,6,4);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got you wrong first, sorry.
You can use GROUP BY, for 2 columns to find the max, and then join the original table.
In your example, this query do the work:

```
SELECT t2.a,t2.b,t2.c 
FROM (SELECT a, b, max(d) as max_d
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY a,b) t1 
inner join TABLE_NAME t2 on(t1.a=t2.a AND t1.b=t2.b AND t1.max_d=t2.d)
```

Comment: it is not that max(d) the OP after. He wants to find the value of the column c where the d is maximum for the pair

Comment: that's better. I am deleting my answer as you have come up with the same answer at the end

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a subquery in the `select` cause, an added bonus is that it will work even if there are duplicate `a, b, d` combinations

```
select 
    a, 
    b,
    (
        select c 
        from T t2 
        where t1.a = t2.a and t1.b = t2.b 
        order by t2.d desc 
        limit 1
    ) c

from T t1
group by a, b;
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can simply SELECT values from columns that are neither grouped nor aggregated, and the output will come from the same row that matches MAX/MIN:

```
SELECT a, b, c, MAX(d)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY a, b
```

Note: this does not work if you omit the `MAX(d)`.

Comment: Thanks! Since I only want columns a, b and c, this approach works if nested in another select. [code]Select a,b,c from (SELECT a, b, c, MAX(d)
FROM T
GROUP BY a, b)[/code]

Comment: That will *not* work because the `MAX(d)` would get optimized away; you *must* have a MAX() that is actually used.

Comment: Hmm, for me too. Apparently, the query optimizer has changed. But I don't know if this behaviour is guaranteed.